# How to hide the output if var = 0

Tags: javascript

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgagT.png)How to hide the output if var m1000 = 0, I want to hide the text1000 for example if i input less than 1000 in the field I want the text1000 or 0 * 1000 Bank Bill to disappear from the output line

```
    function doMoneyExchange() {
        var inp1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("input1").value);
        var m1000 = parseInt(inp1 / 1000);
        var text1000 = m1000 + " * 1000 Bank Bill <br>"
        inp1 = inp1 % 1000;

        if (m1000 == "0") {
            ("text1000").hide();
        }

        var m500 = parseInt(inp1 / 500);
        var text500 = m500 + " * 500 Bank Bill <br>"
        inp1 = inp1 % 500;

        var m100 = parseInt(inp1 / 100);
        var text100 = m100 + " * 100 Bank Bill <br>"
        inp1 = inp1 % 100;

        var out = text1000 + text500 + text100;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = out;
```

[image: output image]

Comment: if statement to check it?

Comment: Yeah how to that I need help with that I tried if (m1000 == 0) {
("text1000").hide();
}
it does not work

Comment: Can you show what you've tried with the if statement?

Comment: So it is `if (m1000 == 0) {} else {} ....` What is your issue?

Comment: The * 1000 line still show up

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use jQuery. Is that correct? `("text1000").hide();` is my evidence. If so, `$("text1000").hide();` might work better.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you're using `$.hide()` incorrectly. This method is used to hide elements but your program is concatenating everything at the end into a single string, which is then output to an HTML element.

What you should do instead is initialize your string variables to an empty string and then assign them a value on the condition that corresponding number variable is greater than 0. For example,

```
var text1000 = "";
if(m1000 > 0) {
    text1000 = m1000 + " * 1000 Bank Bill <br/>";
}
```

Rinse and repeat and your resulting output string should only contain lines for numbers greater than 0.

P.S. If you're intent on using string concatenation for your output, there's no need for multiple substring variables. This makes your code less easily maintained. Rather, consider using a single string variable and concatenating in parts rather than all at the end.

```
var outputString = "";
if(m1000 === "0") {
    outputString = outputString.concat(m1000 + " * 1000 Bank Bill <br>";
}

if(m100 === "0") {
    outputString = outputString.concat(m100 + " * 100 Bank Bill <br>";
}
// repeat
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = outputString;
```